# SpringBoot oauth2 authentication with Access Token

Tags: spring-boot, curl, oauth-2.0

I am building a spring boot application with Oauth2 by pointing it to keyclock server.

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          keycloak:
            client-id: Sandbox-OIDC
            client-secret: <>
            client-name: Auth Server
            scope: user_info
            provider: keycloak
            redirect-uri-template: http://localhost:8000/oauth2
            client-authentication-method: basic
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
        provider:
          keycloak:
            token-uri: https://sample.com/auth/realms/Sandbox/protocol/openid-connect/token
            authorization-uri: https://sample.com/auth/realms/Sandbox/protocol/openid-connect/auth
            user-info-uri: https://sample.com/auth/realms/Sandbox/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
            user-name-attribute: name
```

It works fine with UI login page, but some users are obtaining token directly from keycloack server and then trying to use the obtained token to hit APIs. Is this scenario possible with sprint oauth2..? if yes how to pass the token to the REST endpoints.

I have tried Bearer/Token/Basic Auth headers.

Request

```
curl -i -L -H "Authorization: Token $ACCESS_TOKEN" http://localhost:8000/oauth2
HTTP/1.1 302 
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=472D23F09ECF5A5F883DE218F91A508C; Path=/; HttpOnly
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Location: http://localhost:8000/login?error
Content-Length: 0
Date: Wed, 02 Sep 2020 03:32:52 GMT

HTTP/1.1 200 
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 927
Date: Wed, 02 Sep 2020 03:32:52 GMT

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Please sign in</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/signin/signin.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div class="container">
<h2 class="form-signin-heading">Login with OAuth 2.0</h2><div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Invalid credentials</div><table class="table table-striped">
 <tr><td><a href="/oauth2/authorization/keycloak">Auth Server</a></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
</body></html>
```

Web security configuration **(UPDATED)**

```
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final SecurityHandler securityHandler;

    @Autowired
    SecurityConfiguration(final SecurityHandler securityHandler) {
        this.securityHandler = securityHandler;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers( "/static/*")
                .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().cors().and()
                .addFilterAfter(securityHandler::storeLoggedInUser, FilterSecurityInterceptor.class)
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt();
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {

        final CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.applyPermitDefaultValues();
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return source;
    }
}
```

Comment: It should work with Authorization Header. 
Can you post your request( postman) ?

Comment: updated my post with request details (curl)

Comment: It should be curl -i -L -H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN"

Comment: tried with Bearer and no luck

Comment: Can You post your WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implementation file.

Comment: updated post with WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implementation

Comment: Are you sure that $ACCESS_TOKEN contains the actual token? Also what should happen when you curl this url `http://localhost:8000/oauth2`? What do you expect?

Comment: my expectation is to get session, so that I can use it hit other endpoints

Comment: I guess you will need to configure this application as resource server 
Look this https://www.appsdeveloperblog.com/oauth2-resource-server-and-keycloak/

Comment: updated my security config .. now I am getting.    WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Signed JWT rejected: Another algorithm expected, or no matching key(s) found", error_uri="https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750#section-3.1"
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff